# C# WinForms - Paint method questions

Tags: c#, winforms, onpaint

I am not sure what is the best way of using graphics - should I attach my classes to main form Paint event and then do the drawing, or it is better to call it from overidden OnPaint void like this? I mean, is it OK to do that like this:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e)  //what is this good for? My app works without it as well
    Graphics g=e.Graphics;
    DrawEnemies(g);
    UpdateHUD(g);
    DrawSelectedUnit(g);
}
```

Comment: `OnPain` is not going to compile, unless this is actually a subclass of a class that supports being physically tortured ;)

Comment: Aw @Thomas, you could have just edited that.

Comment: Nah. I'm far too witty for that. (Also, I was recently reprimanded for editing an obvious copy/paste mistake in someone's code, but that wasn't the reason I refrained from editing here.)

Comment: It just left me wondering... OnPain of what? OnPain of execution!

Comment: overriding OnPaint you can comment base.OnPaint for performace reasons. But take care cause you will not recieve OnPaint events anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is recommended that controls override the `On...` methods rather than subscribe to their own events.

You should call `base.OnPaint` to ensure the `Paint` method is fired properly.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx):

> The OnPaint method also enables
>   derived classes to handle the event
>   without attaching a delegate. This is
>   the preferred technique for handling
>   the event in a derived class.
>
> Notes to Inheritors
>   When overriding
>   OnPaint in a derived class, be sure to
>   call the base class's OnPaint method
>   so that registered delegates receive
>   the event.

Comment: usually, overriding OnPaint you don't need to fire Paint events anymore, so base.OnPaint is not mandatory. MSDN tells, but not everything is to follow exactly. In a similar way you override OnBackgroundPaint and comment base.OnBackgroundPaint do NOT base repaint the background - against flickering.

Comment: @serhio: The way to prevent background painting isn't to override OnBackgroundPaint (that's the old school brute force method carried over from Win32). Instead, you should set the Control style to include `AllPaintingInWmPaint`.

Comment: From MSDN: `When overriding OnPaintBackground  in a derived class it is not necessary to call the base class's OnPaintBackground.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaintbackground.aspx

Comment: @serhio: Yup, that's right, but the correct way to prevent flicker only in .NET is the control style. If you want to actually paint a new background, you would do what you describe. Of course, that is all moot for this question as the question regards OnPaint.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't really matter; both work. Overriding `OnPaint` might be ever so slightly faster in theory, but it's not a difference that anyone will notice. Microsoft recommends overriding `OnPaint` but doesn't really motivate this.

You need to call `base.OnPaint` because this method will invoke handlers attached to the `Paint` event.