# What are the advantages of using OnPaint override method over Paint method in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I'm learn various features of C# and I am trying to create a Windows Forms program in which you draw a rectangle.

I understand that onpaint method supposed to override the paint method and overriding helps if you wish to provide a method to the parent class.

In what cases should you use the OnPaint handler

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
```

instead of the regular paint handler

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
```

In another way of asking is what methods do the onpaint method provide that the form1_paint couldn't?

Comment: @Matthew `OnPaint` is not an event, it's a protected method that raises the `Paint` event. You have to [have a protected method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/#events) that raises the event because otherwise it would be impossible to raise the event from derived classes because events are not inherited.

Comment: Oh yea, that makes sense from the names.

Answer (score -2):

According to [C# Winforms - Paint method questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195459/c-sharp-winforms-paint-method-questions) pointed out by Broots, both methods work without much advantage over another. According to Thomas, overriding OnPaint may slightly be faster because OnPaint do not to fire the Paint events.